# JsonResult function put unknown Dictionary item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC i have function

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCard(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Data, int? IDPC)
{
   return Json(new { Data = Data, IDPC: IDPC });
}
```

If i post data through jquery like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/Admin/Hardware/SaveCard",
    type: "POST",
    accept: "application/json",
    data: { Data: [], IDPC: 5 },
    success: function (Response) { }
});
```

Then will return

```
{"Data":{"controller":{},"action":{}},"IDPC":5}
```

See the problem? I wish to been Data null, because ajax don't send Data parameter if is array empty, so request send only IDPC parameter, function SaveCard retrieve only one parameter, second may be null, but isn't. I don't now why and why have Data parameter items like controller and action.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The MVC parser tries to parse the Params dictionary, which contains the controller name and the action name.

If you want to send an empty dictionary, you should explicitly set null value :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/Admin/Hardware/SaveCard",
    type: "POST",
    accept: "application/json",
    data: { Data: null, IDPC: 5 },
    success: function (Response) { }
});
```

This will be parsed into an empty dictionary.

Comment: If i set Data parameter to null, i receive error message "Parameter cannot be null. Parameter name: key."